# PHP SQL Syntax Error by Update

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a problem with my SQL Syntax.. All other SQL-Methods are correct in my files but a UPDATE-Method fails everytime. I can't find the mistake. Please help me.

```
$sql = mysql_query("UPDATE ".$dbName.".'settings' SET 'interval'=".$intervalValue." WHERE 'settingID'=0 ");
```

The error of my debug-method is:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''settings' SET 'interval'=2800 WHERE 'settingID'=0' at line 1
```

Comment: give us the output of `"UPDATE ".$dbName.".'settings' SET 'interval'=".$intervalValue." WHERE 'settingID'=0 "`, it seems `$dbName` is `'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$sql = mysql_query("UPDATE ".$dbName.".`settings` SET 'interval'=".$intervalValue." WHERE 'settingID'=0 ");
```

You should mark databases & tables with "`" instand of "'".

Answer (score 1):

```
$sql = mysql_query('UPDATE `' . $dbName . '`.`settings` SET `interval` = ' . $intervalValue . ' WHERE `settingID` = 0;');
```

Answer (score 0):

You did the quoting wrong. Use single quotes to quote the values and not the column names, use the proper MySQL quoting with ticks for table and column names

```
"UPDATE ".$dbName.".`settings` SET SET `interval`='".$intervalValue."' WHERE `settingID`=0"
```

Answer (score 0):

You should protect your code against SQL injection : [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

```
$sql = mysql_query("UPDATE ".$dbName.".settings SET interval='".$intervalValue."' WHERE settingID=0 ");
```